# Show an input field when <td>Value</td> is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with data results displayed. 
I want to make the values change to an input field when clicked, so that the new value can be entered and submitted.

I have the following script which works ok at displaying the input field, but once displayed i can't click inside the input field to enter a new value.

How do i prevent the input field from responding to the second click?

SCRIPT

```
$(".inputqty").click(function(event) {
            $(this).html('<input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputqty" style="width:50px; height:20px;" type="text" name="<?php echo $prod_var_code; ?>" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>">');
    });
```

RENDERED HTML

```
<td class="inputqty" name="product1">5</td>
<td class="inputqty" name="product2">2</td>
<td class="inputqty" name="product3">8</td>
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: check console for errors

Comment: Could you post an example of your table data ? Chances are that the click isn't responding as the elements are being generated dynamically. So you should use an `on` handler or `delegate`. You can also prevent the event from bubbling up using `event.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: Sorry you can't use php at client side. You have to use ajax for this.

Comment: Tag removed as it's not relevant in the present context.

Comment: the unbind works well. all sorted. cheers

Comment: you are right about php at client side though @NiteshGupta 
maybe it's better to show/hide the value and input?

Comment: If needed, you can still dialogue with PHP through Ajax. All you'd need is a PHP method that can fetch whatever data is needed for a table cell at row, column. Make sure any submissions are done with a POST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to unbind or detach the event from the `<td>`
jQuery has .unbind().

JS:

```
$(".inputqty").click(function (event) {
    $(this).html('Whatever HTML I want');
    $(this).unbind('click');
});
```

Fiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/YGhtm/
```

This will prevent a second click - it would remove the entire binding actually.

Comment: @jason3w: if it helped you, please accept the answer by clicking the tick just under the vote arrows - this helps others to be recognised for their contributions through reputation.  Thanks!

Comment: got it. i just had to wait 4 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevent parent handlers from being notified of the event, like

```
$(document).on('click', 'input-sm', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe others have provided answer that will work for you. I however want to point out things that you should consider in this scenario of yours.

First of, unless necessary **DO NOT** use `<?php ?>` in your jquery. This is because PHP is server side, it gets rendered once before sent to your client. Any more interaction with the client is beyond the capabilities of your PHP server side scripting.

In your case, you can just take the current `name` attribute of your `<td>` for the name of your `<input>` and use the current value in your `<td>` as the `value` attribute of your `<input>`.

I personally recommend using different class name such as `.editing` in addition to your `.inputQty` to signify that it is in the middle of editing.

**UPDATE**: I notice you use the same `id` as well, consider changing that to use your `name` attribute as well.

From the point above, I recommend the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VnnXq/

```
$(".inputqty").click(function(event) {
    $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass('editing'))
    {
        var currentValue = $this.text();
        var name = $this.attr('name');
        $this.html('<input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputqty" style="width:50px; height:20px;" type="text" name="' + name + '" value="' + currentValue + '">');
        $this.addClass('editing');
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".inputqty").click(function (event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.has('input')) {
        $(this).html('<input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputqty" style="width:50px; height:20px;" type="text" name="<?php echo $prod_var_code; ?>" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>">');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also `remove` the class like

```
$(".inputqty").click(function(event) {
        $(this).html('<input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputqty" style="width:50px; height:20px;" type="text" name="<?php echo $prod_var_code; ?>" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>">');
        $(this).removeClass('inputqty');
});
```

Then the `click event` will not work for that.It will be the better option that if you maintain an another class ratherthan `inputqty` and append this event to that new class,and remove,if you want to maintain the `inputqty`.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions work at displaying the input field, however using the php variable in the jquery script doesn't. So the solution i ended up using is this.

HTML/PHP

```
echo '<td>
      <p class="valueqty">' . $qty . '</p>
      <input style="display:none" type="text" name="' . $prod_var_code . '" value="' . $qty . '">
      </td>';
```

SCRIPT

```
$(".valueqty").click(function(event) {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).next().show();
    });
```

Hope this helps someone :)